# How to get another html file as if getting it by document without using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, dom, element, document

How to get another html file as if getting it by document

Basically, the same 'document' instance type used for `document.getElementsByClassName()`, but instead of getting the document the javascript code is in, it gets another .html file in the same domain. For example, "blog.html".

Here's what I want it to hypothetically look like

```
var blogdocument = getDocument("blog.html");
var blogposts = blogdocument.getElementsByClassName("blogpost");
```

Comment: this question seems similar to yours  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add some suggestions to the answer

```
const doc = new DOMParser();
```

You may not want to use const

Because you should use

```
doc = null;
```

to actively release memory after you done with it

DOMParser is very expensive

I have encountered serious performance issues because I didn't do it

[DOM Parser Chrome extension memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451731/dom-parser-chrome-extension-memory-leak)

Answer (score 0):

If it's on the same domain, you can make a network request to get the text of the response back, then send it through DOMParser to construct a document from the text:

```
fetch('./blog.html')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then((result) => {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(result, 'text/html');
    const posts = doc.querySelectorAll('.blogpost');
    // ...
  })
  // .catch(handleErrors);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to a fetch or AJAX request is to load an iframe with the source set to the URL, then read from its `contentWindow`, and then remove it from the DOM.

```js
var desiredPage = "www.google.com";
var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", desiredPage);
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(ifrm.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("somestuff"));
  ifrm.remove();
}, 100);
```